# Не работает POST запрос Spring boot

Tags: spring, post, rest, безопасность, boot

использую spring security и boot, отправляю данные при помощи постмана, данные не доходят 401 ошибка.

```
POST /registration HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 2f772401-e251-4456-9d61-6b61e97c4926,c4af2ad0-0a7b-4f44-a380- 
127fad39f644
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 59
Cookie: JSESSIONID=0867EA3A4911C082EC22931BE2020BD8
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

{"empNo":"E11","empName":"New Employee","position":"Clerk"}
```

Сам контроллер.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee", //
        method = RequestMethod.POST, //
        produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, //
                MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
@ResponseBody
public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {

    System.out.println("(Service Side) Creating employee: " + emp.getEmpNo());

    return emp;
}

package com.example.labksp;
```

Класс

```
public class Employee {

private String empNo;
private String empName;
private String position;

public Employee() {

}

public Employee(String empNo, String empName, String position) {
    this.empNo = empNo;
    this.empName = empName;
    this.position = position;
}

public String getEmpNo() {
    return empNo;
}

public void setEmpNo(String empNo) {
    this.empNo = empNo;
}

public String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}

public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}

public String getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(String position) {
    this.position = position;
}

}
```

Мучаюсь вторую неделю, можете помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот рабочий код

```java
RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class CreateRestController {

    private CreateService createService;

    @Autowired
    public CreateRestController(CreateService createService) {
        this.createService = createService;
    }

    @PostMapping("create")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> create(@RequestBody TargetDto dto) {

        this.createService.createEntry(dto);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

это лишнее

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee", //
        method = RequestMethod.POST, //
        produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, //
                MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
@ResponseBody
```

RestFull Services (rest api) предполагает, что вы работаете с JSON.
 Кроме того, аннотаций столько не надо.

А вот для GEt, может понадобиться вот такое оформление

```java
@RequestMapping(path = "api", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
```

тогда POSTMAN при работе с методом GET не выдаст ошибку

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public class ReadRestController {

    private TargetService targetService;

    private Bot bot;

    @Autowired
    public ReadRestController(TargetService targetService) {
        this.targetService = targetService;
    }


    @GetMapping("name/{town}")
    public TargetDto getDataAboutCity(@PathVariable String town) {

        System.out.println(town);
        return targetService.readEntry(town);

    }
```